# Typescript and Emotion js, conditional props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

Basically in my redux store I have a Boolean state, where I go through props to use conditionals when applying css
But for some reason mine:

> background: $ {(props: HamburguerProps) => (props.open? 'red':
>   'pink')};

always stays red even if the state is true or false

TSX:

```
interface RootState {
  sideBarStatus: boolean;
}

interface SideBar {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

const LogoNavigation: React.FC<SideBar> = ({ isOpen }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <LogoSide open={isOpen} xd={isOpen ? 'blue' : 'pink'}>
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo Elo Ghost" />
      <Hamburguer
        open={isOpen}
        onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSide(!isOpen))}
      >
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </Hamburguer>
    </LogoSide>
  );
};
const SideNavigation: React.FC = () => {
  // const { sideIsOpen } = useSelector((RootState) => RootState.toggleSide);
  const selectIsOpen = (state: RootState) => state.sideBarStatus;
  const sideBarStatus = useSelector(selectIsOpen);
  console.log('sideBar', sideBarStatus);
  return (
    <SideNav>
      <LogoNavigation isOpen={sideBarStatus} />
    </SideNav>
  );
};
```

CSS:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

type HamburguerProps = {
  open: boolean;
};
export const LogoSide = styled.div<HamburguerProps>`
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: ${(props: HamburguerProps) => (props.open ? 'red' : 'pink')};
  img {
    height: 50px;
  }
`;
```

An example gif where I show my state changing from true to false and yet my style does not change:

[image]

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-galileo-zp3e7?file=/src/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isOpen` isn't a `boolean`, it's an object containing `sideIsOpen` key with a `boolean` value. An `object` is always truthy, that's why your background is always *red*.

```
open={isOpen.sideIsOpen}
```

or even better - use destructuring with the selector:

```
const { sideIsOpen } = useSelector(selectIsOpen);

isOpen={sideIsOpen}
```

Comment: i got this Property 'sideIsOpen' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

Comment: @Felipe because you have to also tweak on your interface. Check my edit :)

Comment: I edited the answer with all code I couldn't do it could you help me?

Comment: @Felipe Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-field-8exx2

Comment: i had a problem with this:

Property 'toggleSide' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts (2339)

Comment: I didn't understand the reason I modified my reducer, but I still have an error

Comment: @Felipe Maybe `DefaultRootState.ts` is not typed properly? (does not have `sideIsOpen` field)

Comment: i  got this with console.log on RootState: toggleSide: {sideIsOpen: false}

Comment: @Felipe Can you update your codesandbox and pass me the link? I will fix it for you

Comment: I don't know why, but in my codesandbox the same example works normally wtf

Comment: const selectIsOpen = (state: RootState) => state.toggleSide;
  const {sideIsOpen} = useSelector (selectIsOpen);


I tried it but got this error:

Property 'sideIsOpen' does not exist on type 'Boolean'.

Comment: @Felipe You need to change from `yourField: boolean` to `yourField: { sideIsOpen: boolean }`

Comment: Can you help me? I did this and continues with the error: / isOpen: { sideIsOpen: boolean };

Comment: @Felipe Should be okey right now, can you provide me updated codesandbox? I will fix it for you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-thunder-fl1xj?file=/src/App.tsx this but work I don't understand how it works on my codesand and not on the site, I don't know if the reason is eslint.

Comment: @Felipe https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-germain-s0cs6?file=/src/App.tsx